# WPF TextBox reacting weirdly with stringformat 0:N2

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, string-formatting

This is hard to explain so please look at the WPF gif below -

I have a textbox with a stringformat {0:N2} and bound to a property.

[image]

There are two problems here -

(1) When hitting the decimal key, another decimal is added.

(2) During backspace, after deleting the decimal digits - the caret doesn't jump over the decimal rather starts adding '00' to the number itself.

I did a workaround for point (1) -

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Decimal)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ((TextBox)sender).CaretIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

If there is a better way to handle such things in application - please do let me know.

Now, how do I handle the second problem? The workaround Im trying to implement is - if decimal point reached, handle the key press and move the caret position. Not sure if this is a good solution and if so, how to know when I have reached the decimal point?

Comparing the caret index to the length of the textbox value just to know if it has reached the decimal point seems like overdoing it. What is the correct solution to these 2 problems?

Comment: I guess you have UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" in your binding. If you remove that, does the textbox behave more like you wanted?

Comment: oh wow! yes removing that, did make it behave normally. Changed the sourcetrigger to lostfocus as it still gives me the behavior i need. Why does 'PropertyChanged' make it behave like that? Also, If you can post that as an answer, I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to when the stringformat is being applied to the value.

Which is as the value comes back from the binding Source ( the bound string property ) to the TextBox Text ( the Target ).

And it's linked to metadata of textpropety.

The Textbox TextProperty binds twoway, this is set in the metadata of that dependency property.

The default behaviour of a textbox is to copy the value to the bound source when the control loses focus.

If you use that then the n2 format is applied once the user has finished editing. They may fix up whatever they like with the zeroes and decimal point and the format only gets applied when they tab away.

By contrast, if you set UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" in your binding then you will find it behaves weirdly. This is because the user types a letter, the whole value is transferred to the bound property which notifies the control it changed.
All sorts of weird bad things happen as the formatting is being applied.

It's possible that this is an edge case whoever built the textbox didn't consider.